# Reset UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger with button

Tags: swift, unusernotificationcenter

I'm trying to reset a `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` to sent a notification multiple times. I've tried a few things, including:

-Set `repeats: true` -> This crashes my application somehow, giving me the error `thread 1 signal sigabrt`

Now the problem with the current code (see below) is that I get the error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'trigger'`. Now for as far as I understand this error shows me that I can't use trigger because it is set in a button 'function' and that it can't find `let trigger`.

**Question:** How do I make the function resetTimer see `trigger`? Or is there a better way to reset UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger?

```
@IBAction func change(_ sender: Any) {
func startTimer() {
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: TimeInterval(tijd), repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: bezigheid, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }
}

func resetTimer() {
    trigger.invalidate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this code is completely incorrect.
It's not ment to put functions inside @IBActions. 
Do it like this:

```
@IBAction func startTimer(_ sender: Any) {
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: TimeInterval(tijd), repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: bezigheid, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}

@IBAction func resetTimer(_ sender: Any) {
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: TimeInterval(tijd), repeats: false)
    trigger.invalidate
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Although it doesn't really work. The error I get is: `Value of type 'UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger' has no member 'invalidate'` (pointing at `trigger.invalidate`) Also, can I start the timer while pressing the second (resetTimer) button? Because now it only resets the timer, right?

Comment: This means that the function "invalidate" does not exists.

Comment: So then I add it, how? `func invalidate { //Something? }` and then `trigger.invalidate()` ?

Comment: You can add that function above the @IBAction and then use something like self.invalidate.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what to put in the invalidate function because usually (?) it just worked when I set it to `timer.invalidate` in that case. Can you maybe sent the code as an edit of your answer? If it works I can mark it as solved!

Comment: Yes because .invalidate is not a function. What do you want to reach by using the .invalidate function?

Comment: Because if you want to remove it you should use something like: `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests`

Comment: So I want this notification to run again when the user taps a certain button, meaning that the button should reset the trigger, right? (UNTimeIntervalWithNotification) The time interval is 3 days so when pressing the button the notification should pop up in 3 days again, and again 3 days later when the user presses the button.

Comment: Do you think you can help me out?